# Legendre Symbol $(\frac{-19}{p})$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How would one say for what primes the legendre symbol $\left(\frac{-19}{p}\right)$ is equal to $1$? By Reciprocity, $$\left(\frac{-19}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{p}{19}\right)(-1)^{9(p-1)/2}=\left(\frac{p}{19}\right)(-1)^{5(p-1)/2},$$ but how can we simplify this further?

Comment: The final expression should be $\left(\frac{p}{19}\right)(-1)^{5(p-1)}=\left(\frac{p}{19}\right)$ since $5(p-1)$ is always even. Now it suffices to find the quadratic residues modulo $19$.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your calculations $-$ doing $p=2$ by hand, we can assume $2\mid(p-1)$ so

$$\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)(-1)^{9(p-1)/2}=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}(-1)^{9(p-1)/2}=(-1)^{10(p-1)/2}=(-1)^{5(p-1)}=1.$$

Therefore you simply seek $\left(\frac{p}{19}\right)$. Consider $p$'s residue mod $19$.